# Compare two sorted arrays and find missing elements between them

Tags: algorithm

I have two arrays that are lexically sorted:

Array1 is a kind of sorted superset of Array2 that is all the elements in Array2 will also be in Array1 but not vice versa.

```
Array1: [A,B,C,D,E,F,G]

Array2: [B,C,F]

Result: [A,D,E,G]
```

The result will have the missing elements not present in Array2 but in Array1.

I am looking for the best optimal solution.

One of my logic was to use a binary search but I am stuck thinking about how to implement it.

Any help on a correct algorithm would be great.

Edit: Duplicates are allowed.

Comment: `Edit: Duplicates are allowed.` Great. How are duplicates in *A* to be handled? How about  duplicates in *B*?

Answer (score 0):

This O(n) and can be achieved by iterating through the superset while keeping a pointer to the most recently matched element in the subset and noting which superset elements are absent from the subset.

An implementation in C#:

```
char[] superset = new char[] { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G' };
char[] subset = new char[] { 'B', 'C', 'F' };

List<char> missing = new List<char>();
int subIdx = 0;
foreach (var element in superset)
{
    if (subIdx < subset.Length && subset[subIdx] == element)
        subIdx++;
    else
        missing.Add(element);
}

var result = missing.ToArray(); // If you need an array rather than list
```

Comment: Small question: Can we do better than O(n)? I feel like there is some kind of a binary search solution to this since they are sorted. I might be wrong

Comment: One can't do better than O(length of array1) since once the last element of array2 is seen, the rest of array1 must be copied to output.  In the worst case (array2 is empty) that requires a full iteration of array1.

Comment: Indeed, the sorting is why this can be achieved in O(n).